Conditionally deserialize a csv record using serde
I'm parsing a csv table, doing some processing and exporting a JSON file. The CSV records are abriged Grafana panels, so I have some structs to abstract the gridPos, targets, alert, and other fields. Grafana also has rows, and they're a lot simpler than panels, having only a grid position, a title and a type attribute. I'd like to check if the first column of the row I'm currently processing is "__row", and then skip deserializing most fields if that's the case. Unfortunately, Serde doesn't have a skip_deserializing_if macro, so I'm looking for a workaroud. Here's what I tried:
let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_reader(file);
for record in rdr.deserialize() {
  if record.unwrap().name == "__row" {
    // do some things
    continue;
  }

  // Record is an struct that abstracts my template csv record
  let record: Record = record?;
  // continue as usual if it's a regular panel, and not a row


This doesn't work, and I get the following error message:
   |
68 |     for record in rdr.deserialize() {
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `D` declared on the method `deserialize`
69 |
70 |         if record.unwrap().name == "__row" {
   |            --------------- type must be known at this point
   |
help: consider specifying the generic argument
   |
68 |     for record in rdr.deserialize::<D>() {
   |                                  +++++

I tried changing the function signature to pub fn process_alerts<D: for<'de> serde::Deserialize<'de>>, but that made me notice it won't solve my problem, because calling record.as_ref().unwrap() will still panic, and I need some way to access the name field even when the other Record fields are null.
What would be a good solution for this? I don't want to make every Record field Option<T>, nor use #[serde(default)], as I want the app to error out if there's unknown variants specified when a regular panel is being parsed.
new edit: this excerpt is a summary of the problem. I've also included a reproducible examp that can be run on the Rust Playground
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use csv::Reader;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
#[serde(rename_all(deserialize = "snake_case"))]
enum Foo {
    Bar,
    Ham,
    Eggs
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Clone)]
struct Record{
    name: String,
    foo: Foo,
    baz: String,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let data = "\
    name,foo,baz
    Panel 1,bar,my text
    __row,,
";
    let mut rdr = Reader::from_reader(data.as_bytes());

    for record in  rdr.deserialize() {
        let _record: &Record = record.as_ref().unwrap();

        if &_record.name == "__row" {
          // do some things
          continue;
        }

        let record: Record = record?;
        // do something else...
  }

  Ok(())


  // this will panic when reading the second csv record
  /*
  thread 'main' panicked at src/main.rs:28:48:
  called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error(Deserialize { pos: Some(Position { byte: 37, line: 3, record: 2 }), err: 
  DeserializeError { field: None, kind: Message("unknown variant ``, expected one of `bar`, `ham`, `eggs`") } })
  */

}

Essencially, I'd need a way to skip_deserializing_if, which would allow me to handle differently the csv records that have __row as the first column value.

Please follow the compilers advice: help: consider specifying the generic argument You have to tell it what type you expect because CSV doesn't contain that info and your further code doesn't inform it either. unwrap can be called on 2 types in std and nothing stops anybody from adding it to their type either.

that leads me straight into the weird trait rabbit hole and it just feels so hacky

should just be .deserialize::<YourType>()

It seems like you need to create a struct and implement Deserialize manually on it. This struct will be the  generic parameter you send into rdr.deserialize. It can be annoying to implement Deserialize manually, but I wouldn't consider it hacky. Read about their data model.

Please add a [mre] including your type.

@cafce25 added the Record definition and what I tried

That's by no means minimal and also still missing the input you give it.

What is the problem with your current code?

I added a summary example of my problem, and tried to explain myself better. The problem is that the current code will panic, because it will deserialize the same way independent of csv's first column value

CSV is a quite limited format, so proper handling of this is quite difficult. You can do it the easy way and without changing the structs (so changing the rest of the program unnecessarily) by just skipping error rows:
for record in rdr.deserialize::<Record>() {
    let Ok(record) = record else {
        continue;
    };
}

